# Mootools: how to check child element?

Tags: mootools

HTML:

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
    <li class="mainmenu-item">Menu 1
        <ul class="mainmenu-child">
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <li>Menu3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$$('#mainmenu li').addEvents({
    'mouseenter':function() {
    alert(this.contains($$('.mainmenu-child')));
    }
```

});

Always false. 
 
Tried to use hasChild() method = same result, always false.
How to check has an element a child or not ? Need boolean type as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work BUT:

```
$$('#mainmenu li').addEvents({
    'mouseenter': function() {
        var hasChild = !!this.getElement('ul.mainmenu-child'); // falsy/truthy.
        console.log(hasChild);
    }
});
```

The problem is, you use mouseenter on a matching li that also has children li that have their own event. so if you mouseover a child element, the mouseenter on the parent will also fire, so you will get a true and a false. you need to add extra checks if it's a root el or not etc.

checking if an element is there is simply requesting the element - if a match is found, it will return an object or null/undefined otherwise (falsy).

Comment: Thanks, i'll think about that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only check 1 element.

And if you're using a selector, just do this.getChildren(selector).length > 0